# AudioSource.PlayOneShot volume increase and clipping

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio

I have been trying to learn about Audio in Unity and am facing an issue where the volume increases to the point where it is noticeably clipping.

The sound is triggered by

```
GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(sound);
```

and it seems that it sometimes gets triggered multiple times, which leads to a volume increase and sometimes clipping.

I have tried using `Play()` and `Stop()` to solve the issue, but this led to all of the other audio being cut too. I haven't had much success trying to create new Audio Sources, but this might be due to my lack of knowledge in this area.

What would be the best way to prevent this issue? Can I declare multiple Audio Sources from one game object or should I be looking elsewhere?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Managed to fix it!
The issue was, that there was only a single audio source available. Therefore the solution is to create a second audio source and in the script use

```
public AudioSource[] sounds;

void PlaySound (AudioClip sound)
{
    sounds = GetComponents<AudioSource>();
    AudioSource audioSource = sounds[1]; //Using the second AudioSource
    audioSource.clip = sound;
    audioSource.Stop(); //Stop any previous audio from playing
    audioSource.Play();

}
```

Big thank you to - https://answers.unity.com/questions/52017/2-audio-sources-on-a-game-object-how-use-script-to.html

EDIT: Improved code. The above code again would allow only one clip to play at a time, so I decided to take it further and create code for each clip as it starts playing. Here is the final code

```
public Dictionary<string,AudioSource> sounds = new Dictionary<string, AudioSource>();

void PlayOneShotSound (AudioClip sound)
{
    //Check if AudioSource has been created for this clip
    if (!sounds.ContainsKey(sound.name)) 
    {
        sounds.Add(sound.name, gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>());
    }
    AudioSource audioSource = sounds[sound.name]; //Using AudioSource for the clip

    audioSource.clip = sound;

    audioSource.Stop(); //Preventing previous sound from being played
    audioSource.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an audio source for each gameobject you want to play a sound? If so, try to create a single gameobject (let's call Audio Source Holder) that only contains an audio source component.

With that in mind, you can have a reference to this Audio Source component and call PlayOneShot(sound) from the script you want to trigger the sound.

For example, let's suppose every time a bullet is fired, we want to play the sound:

```
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour {
     // This AudioSource reference comes from the Audio Source Holder gameobject
     public AudioSource audioSource;

     public void PlayFireSound(){
         audioSource.PlayOneShot(sound);
     }
}
```

Hope the above helps. You can also take a look at this [question](https://answers.unity.com/questions/896387/multiple-playoneshot-bug.html) where the audio file is changed to an uncompressed format, like .wav, to see if your problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The main issue I am having is the volume increase which comes from the audio being played multiple times at once. Wouldn't the above code have the same problem?